# Rendering with OpenGL in Blender does not show the intended rendered image or animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, opengl

I am trying to render animations and images fast using the OpenGL feature in Blender but even though I want it to render a fully rendered image or animation, it only renders the solid image, or the material image, or texture or wireframe. Basically it renders in every other way except the rendered type I want. 
Please help me see what I do wrong. 
Here are some screenshots.

The first is how i want it rendered.

The second is how it actually renders when I press the little camera icon, NOT what I want.

The 3rd is to compare, I want a wireframe render

And the 4th shows the wireframe render, exactly how is supposed to be.

Please help!

[image: The first is how i want it rendered.]
[image: The second is how it actually renders when I press the little camera icon, NOT what I want.][image: The 3rd is to compare, I want a wireframe render][image: and the 4th shows the wireframe render, exactly how is supposed to be.]

Comment: First render isn't Open GL. It is a viewport/preview render, which is basically final render with less number of samples. You currently have 100 samples for final render and 32 for preview, less samples means faster rendering but also noisier.